# How to print a voxel object?

Tags: 3d-design, software, file-formats

I recently downloaded Magicavoxel to give this voxel thing a try, and I was curious if there was a way to turn the voxel files into a file for printing?

Magicavoxel doesn't seem to offer a way to export the project as STL.

Comment: One does *not* include the answers in the tagging - one tags questions based on the problem - in this case, the question is about "What do I need to do with this program? It does not offer STL!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magicavoxel supports export as `.obj`, natively or with the right [plugin](https://gist.github.com/shivshank/34ffc56283273e1e904e8dc50491a7a6).

While `.stl` is the standard for 3d-printing exchanges, as it contains a "1-unit" length,(typically that corresponds to 1 mm), `.obj` is also accepted by most slicers.

To get to MagicaVoxel's native export, look in the lower right corner, click export and see this pop up:

[image: Export menu]

Press the top-left `OBJ` option and you get a save position window where you can store it. Then open it with your slicer and choose a scale - most `.obj` files do not contain a scale as the format does not contain a unit measure by default like `.stl` and has to be given one.